# Long-tap/drag/drop Skobbler skannotation to new position

Tags: ios, objective-c, skmaps

I'm looking to allow my users to drag & drop annotations on my maps, initiated by a long-press on the annotation pin. I can't find anything in the documentation that would handle this.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

**Edit:** I realize I may not have been as clear as I thought I was.

Currently, my users are able to add new annotations to the map by long-pressing at a location on the map. I'd like for them to be able to move those annotations to a different location.

Comment: Are you trying to position a new PIN (annotation) or re-position an existing PIN (annotation)?

Comment: I'm trying to re-position an existing annotation.

Answer (score 0):

For adding a new PIN, the SKMapViewDelegate protocol is used to receive map-related update messages.
Check: http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/ios/2.4.0/Protocols/SKMapViewDelegate.html